# Merge/Combine some item which have same status in listview

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I want to show my JSON data in listview, here my json structure

```
{"result":[
 {"id":1,
  "status":"New",
  "revenue":3000},
 {"id":2,
  "status":"Qualified",
  "revenue":10000},
 {"id":3,
  "status":"New",
  "revenue":2000}
 ]
}
```

In listview, I want to show data with same status will show in one row and for revenue I will sum that. I already can show result of sum revenue but i cant set that in one row. My coding will look like this like this[image]

Is this possible for show same data in one row?

Here my code

```
_rn_request_listener = new RequestNetwork.RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String _param1, String _param2, HashMap<String, Object> _param3) {
            final String _tag = _param1;
            final String _response = _param2;
            final HashMap<String, Object> _responseHeaders = _param3;
            detail = new HashMap<>();
            master = new HashMap<>();
            detail = new Gson().fromJson(_response, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
            str= (new Gson()).toJson(detail.get("result"), new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>(){}.getType());
            str2 = detail.get("count").toString().replace(".0","");
            count_opportunity.setText(str2);
            listmap_detail = new Gson().fromJson(str, new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>(){}.getType());
            Double revenue= Double.valueOf(0);
            Double count = Double.valueOf(0);
           
            for (int i=0;i<listmap_detail.toArray().length;i++){
                count+=1;
                 revenue+=Double.parseDouble(listmap_detail.get(i).get("planned_revenue").toString());

            }
            count_opportunity.setText(String.valueOf(count).replace(".0",""));
            total_revenue.setText(String.valueOf(revenue).replace(".0",""));
            SketchwareUtil.sortListMap(listmap_detail, "create_date", false, false);
            listViewopportunity.setAdapter(new OpportunitySalesActivity.ListviewdataAdapter(listmap_detail));
            ((BaseAdapter)listViewopportunity.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(String _param1, String _param2) {

        }
    };
```

Myadapter

```
public class ListviewdataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> _data;
    public ListviewdataAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> _arr) {
        _data = _arr;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Object> getItem(int _index) {
        return _data.get(_index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int _index) {
        return _index;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int _position, View _v, ViewGroup _container) {
        LayoutInflater _inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View _view = _v;
        if (_view == null) {
            _view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.c_opportunity, null);
        }else{
            _view = _v;
        }

        final TextView t_stage = (TextView) _view.findViewById(R.id.c_stage);
        final TextView t_countstage = (TextView) _view.findViewById(R.id.c_countstage);
        final TextView t_revenue = (TextView) _view.findViewById(R.id.c_totalrevenue);
        final TextView t_customer = (TextView) _view.findViewById(R.id.c_namacustomer);
        final TextView t_expectedrevenue = (TextView) _view.findViewById(R.id.c_expectedrevenue);
        final TextView t_activity = (TextView) _view.findViewById(R.id.c_acitivitytype);

        t_stage.setText(_data.get(_position).get("stage_id").toString().replace("{name=","").replace("}",""));

        Double count_new = Double.valueOf(0);
        Double count_qualified = Double.valueOf(0);
        Double count_covering= Double.valueOf(0);
        Double count_closing = Double.valueOf(0);
        Double count_won = Double.valueOf(0);
        Double new_revenue = Double.valueOf(0);
        Double qualified_revenue = Double.valueOf(0);
        Double covering_revenue = Double.valueOf(0);
        Double closing_revenue = Double.valueOf(0);
        Double won_revenue = Double.valueOf(0);
        for(int i=0;i< _data.size();i++){
            if(_data.get(i).get("stage_id").toString().replace("{name=","").replace("}","").equals("New")){
                count_new+=1;
                new_revenue+=Double.parseDouble(_data.get(i).get("planned_revenue").toString());
            }else if (_data.get(i).get("stage_id").toString().replace("{name=","").replace("}","").equals("Qualified")){
                count_qualified+=1;
                qualified_revenue+=Double.parseDouble(_data.get(i).get("planned_revenue").toString());
            }else if (_data.get(i).get("stage_id").toString().replace("{name=","").replace("}","").equals("Covering")){
                count_covering+=1;
                covering_revenue+=Double.parseDouble(_data.get(i).get("planned_revenue").toString());
            }else if (_data.get(i).get("stage_id").toString().replace("{name=","").replace("}","").equals("Closing")){
                count_closing+=1;
                closing_revenue+=Double.parseDouble(_data.get(i).get("planned_revenue").toString());
            }else{
                count_won+=1;
                won_revenue+=Double.parseDouble(_data.get(i).get("planned_revenue").toString());
            }
        }

        if (t_stage.getText().toString().equals("New")){
            t_countstage.setText(String.valueOf(count_new));
            t_revenue.setText(String.valueOf(new_revenue));
        }else if(t_stage.getText().toString().equals("Qualified")){
            t_countstage.setText(String.valueOf(count_qualified));
            t_revenue.setText(String.valueOf(qualified_revenue));
        }else if(t_stage.getText().toString().equals("Covering")){
            t_countstage.setText(String.valueOf(count_covering));
            t_revenue.setText(String.valueOf(covering_revenue));
        }else if(t_stage.getText().toString().equals("Closing")){
            t_countstage.setText(String.valueOf(count_closing));
            t_revenue.setText(String.valueOf(closing_revenue));
        }else{
            t_countstage.setText(String.valueOf(count_won));
            t_revenue.setText(String.valueOf(won_revenue));
        }



        return _view;
    }
}
```

Edit 1 = I think my thread not clear enough for some people so i add my expected result.[image]

Comment: I'm not an Android expert but getting that data into one row would either require much smaller text or a scrollable component/container.

Comment: Update... i have added my expected result pic

Answer (score 0):

To display all the data with same status in one row, all you need to do is implement **Horizontal ListView/Recycler View**.

Take a look at [this example here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-listview-in-android) on how to implement horizontal list view.

You will need to implement multiple list views depending on how many status you have i.e. 1 Horizontal List View for New. 1 Horizontal List View for Qualified constraint under the above list view and so on

Comment: Update... i have added expected result pic, Can you check that?

Comment: oh, so you want to display just 1 row for same status and add the sum for all with same status?

Comment: Yes, like in expected result pic

Comment: Just make a simple array having length equal to Status you have. Each index represents each status. In your Bind View Holder, check if value at that index is non-negative. If it is, don't bind the data and just sum the value in it. Meanwhile in your activity/Fragment, just get the value of Status at that index and assign it to respective TextView

Comment: Can you give me example for "simple array" as you say? I still not understand for that part

Comment: `Map<String, Int> map = new HashMap<String, Int>();
map.put("new", 100);`